# Why passing loop into adb shell not working when running it inside shell do?

Tags: android, adb, android-shell

This construction failing

```
adb shell "for i in `seq 10`; do command; done"
```

But if run it separately it just fine

```
adb shell
root@vbox86p:/ # for i in `seq 10`; do command; done
```

Am I missing something?

**Update:**

Max OSX with zsh

Comment: initial parsing of your command is done by your host OS/shell, which you provided no information about

Comment: `adb shell 'for i in $(seq 10); do command; done'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this command and it worked for me:

```
adb shell "for i in 'seq 10'; do echo "1"; done"
```

Try to change the quotation symbols in the loop.

Edit:

Try this instead:

```
adb shell "for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "1"; done"
```

Comment: interesting, but it will work out only once inside and outside the adb shell,  when should repeat 10 times. The old quotation do work properly but only inside of adb shell

Comment: Try this:
adb shell "for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "1"; done"

Comment: cool, thanks it's totally working, seems the problem was with passing quotations, plz edit your answer

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help out. For some reason you can not push  "seq 10" to adb shell and have to use 1 2 3 4 instead.